# Is there an XSS injection risk when using json_encode to print javascript variables from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, xss, code-injection

When using `json_encode` to print variables from PHP to javascript like :

```
const field = <?= json_encode($_GET['field']) ?>;
```

Is there any XSS or other injection risk ? These variables won't be used in any SQL related task but javascript only. I don't want the user to be able to pass/execute any JS code through the GET parameter.

EDIT : I can't seem to get a definite answer so I'll try to ask it differently : I want to print `$_GET['field']` and be guaranteed that whatever it's contents are, it'll be in the `field` constant as a string, what's the best way to achieve that ? I'm using `json_encode($_GET['field'], JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` at the moment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is json\_encode Sufficient XSS Protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062146/is-json-encode-sufficient-xss-protection)

Comment: @Samurai8 Not really, they say it's not made for protection against XSS attacks, but they don't actually give a concrete example of how they could be exploited.