# How do you pass a PHP array to JS for use in a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

**Context**

I'm building a WordPress Theme Template and am trying to pass an array of data from a Advanced Custom Fields > Repeater Field, using PHP and core WordPress functions, to a JavaScript / HTML5 pie chart.

**The Problem**

I don't know how to pass the PHP data to JS in a format JS understands.

**The Questions**

I'm not confident I'm asking the questions correctly, or thinking about the problem correctly. For example, I believe I can use JS to communicate directly with the database. But here's what I think the questions are:

- How do you pass a PHP array outside of a loop and into a format readable in JS?
- What are some links to training materials or courses on the subject?

**Code**

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if( have_rows('tpc_psmr_referrer') ):
  while ( have_rows('tpc_psmr_referrer') ) : the_row();
        $tpc_psmr_referrer_type = get_sub_field('tpc_psmr_referrer_type');
        $tpc_psmr_referrer_platform = get_sub_field('tpc_psmr_referrer_type_platform'); // This needs to get passed as an array to the JS below.
  endwhile;
endif;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2], // This is where the PHP array needs to be output.
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Revenue'
  };

  var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart1'));

  chart1.draw(data1, options);

  var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Budget'
  };

  var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart2'));

  chart2.draw(data2, options);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you going to make an ajax request to your php from javascript?

Comment: use data-attributes and output the PHP variable to it (and json_encode it - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). You can then retrieve from JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: @BenDubuisson That's one way to do it, but I'd argue to rather put the JSON in an invisible element to avoid any chance of XSS  ( https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233.1_-_HTML_escape_JSON_values_in_an_HTML_context_and_read_the_data_with_JSON.parse )

Comment: @JakubJudas an invisible element does not prevent from XSS

Comment: @BenDubuisson true, but it does make escaping more foolproof (example: a beginner could use single quotes in html but escape using htmlentities with default settings). But maybe I'm paranoid and I'm definitely off topic so I'll stop now.

Comment: @cHao that article is exclusive to variables and my question is regarding arrays. Thanks though!

Comment: @SpencerHill: The answer doesn't change just because your array is or isn't in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Look at json_encode()'ing the values in your while loop, and echoing the data structure that holds them, in the PHP script. $.ajax() request the script, and parse/appropriate the JSON returned on the front end in the success callback.

More specifically, for links to more information on the mechanisms involved in the process, look at json_encode at php.net (Example 1 is straightforward):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

and the jQuery API documentation on $.ajax:

[http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

**SCRIPT.PHP**

```
<?php 

  header("Content-type: application/json");

  $data_array = ['one','two','three'];
  $json = json_encode($data_array);
  echo $json;

?>
```

**JS**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/the/path/to/script.php',
        dataType:'JSON',
        data:{
        },
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data,function(x,y) {
                console.log(data[x]);
            });  
        },
        error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
            console.log('Could not retrieve JSON');
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $data_array = [1,2,3...]; ?>

<html>
  <div id='yellowstone' hidden>
     <?php echo json_encode($data_array); ?>
  </div>
</html>


<script>
     var array = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('yellowstone').innerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: If you're doing that, might as well output it straight as a Javascript variable.
`<script>
     var array = <?php echo json_encode($data_array); ?>;
</script>`

Comment: Unnecessarily commingling the markup, js, and php using this sort of approach. It's cleaner to request the data from a dedicated php script.

Comment: @mdlanglais example?

Comment: @Frank See my answer above, I added a basic working example. You can do what you want with the values returned in the callback at that point. This way your concerns are kept separate, js in a js file, server-side code in its own script.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a function called [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/). It allows you to pass an array to your script and then access it in your JS as an object.
For example:

```
wp_localize_script( 'your_script', 'your_script_data',
    array( 
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'var_1' => 'value 1',
        'var_2' => 'value 2',
    )
);
```

Then somewhere in your JS

```
alert(your_script_data.var_1)
```

will display `value 1`

P.S. `ajax_url` contains and URL to make your AJAX calls in case you need that too. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) is some explanation on that.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it could work but a couple clarifying questions: The docs state the model for wp_localize_script are `wp_localize_script( string $handle, string $object_name, array $l10n )` but your model suggests handle to become my script path? And localization be my array. So it seems like that would output an error.

Comment: @SpencerHill that's exactly how it works. There won't be any error. Handle is the name you gave your script when you enqueued it (1st parameter of `wp_enqueue_script`) and yes, localization is in fact your array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
<?php
$php_var = [['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2], 
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]];
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = <?= json_encode($php_var, JSON_HEX_TAG) . ';' ?>   
</script>
```

See this [PHPFiddle](https://eval.in/1000695).

Other usefull links:

[how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function)

[pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function)

Comment: Why did you use JSON_HEX_TAG? The docs on that state that's for replacing < and > with their unicode value.

Comment: Yes, I used JSON_HEX_TAG for security issues, because passing in a raw string to JSON encode can lead to XSS attacks. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816787/json-php-to-javascript-safe-or-not/6817147#6817147 .