# PHP HP Fortify sends unvalidated data to a web browser, which can result in the browser executing malicious code

Tags: php, xss, fortify

I have a PHP script as below:

```
10. $json_sanitized = ds($json);
11. echo json_encode ( $json_sanitized );
```

The `ds()` function has few rules to sanitize the `$json` data.

```
function ds($text, $double = true, $charset = null) {
  if (is_array($text)) {
    // Some code
  } elseif (is_object($text)) {
    // Some code
  } elseif (is_bool($text)) {
    // Some code
  }

  $defaultCharset = 'UTF-8';

  if (is_string($double)) {
    $charset = $double;
  }

  return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, ($charset) ? $charset : $defaultCharset, $double);
}
```

But the HP Fortify Scanner still says, Line #11, sends unvalidated data to a web browser, which can result in the browser executing malicious code.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Do you need to have all issues mitigated, or be able to document them?

Comment: I have to resolve this issue first.

Answer (score 0):

Per a few other answers on this site, the `json_encode` function in PHP is generally safe, and there are some options that can help make it safer though additional escaping.

Using the following helps to escape more potentially unsafe characters that Fortify picks up:

`echo json_encode($json_sanitized,JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS);`

Per the `json_encode` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and the json constants [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php), these constants provide the following (optional) conversions:

- JSON_HEX_QUOT - All " are converted to \u0022.
- JSON_HEX_TAG - All < and > are converted to \u003C and \u003E.
- JSON_HEX_AMP - All &s are converted to \u0026.
- JSON_HEX_APOS - All ' are converted to \u0027.

You may be able to skip the escaping of the single and double quotes, as I imagine the biggest gripe is that <> are able to be printed unescaped.

[Json: PHP to JavaScript safe or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816787/json-php-to-javascript-safe-or-not/6817147#6817147)
[Is json_encode Sufficient XSS Protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062146/is-json-encode-sufficient-xss-protection)